# Is bounded real analytic function always zero?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f:\Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$ be a real analytic function, if $|f|$ is bounded, does this implies that $f$ is constant zero? I know by the liouville theorem, if $f$ is some holomorphic function, then it's constant .

- Is it possible to let $f$ being non constant but bounded?
- If $|f| \to 0$ as $|x|\to \infty$ , does this implies $f$ is constant function then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sin(x), \cos(x)$ are real analytic and bounded.

$e^{-x^2}$ is real analytic and goes to $0$ as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question does all the function in Schwartz space analytic?

Comment: Not really. Schwartz spaces contain smooth functions that might not be analytic, such as [the bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function)

Comment: I got it thank you.